# I cannot access object in java

Tags: java, class, jinternalframe

i am new at Java and have some problems about swing. I want an application which has some internal frame when user calls by menubar.

```
import java.awt.Color;

import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class uygulama {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("uygulama adı");  

            JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
            frame.add(desktop);

            menubar  mb = new menubar(); //Jmenubar inst.
            frame.setJMenuBar(mb);

            frame.setBounds(300,100,500,300);
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println(desktop.getTopLevelAncestor());

        }
    }); 
  }

}
```

In the code above (the listener code block);  i cant access 'desktop' object. If i could, i would use 'desktop.add()'  to add an JInternalFrame.

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPopupMenu;


public class menubar extends JMenuBar {

    JMenu Dosya;
    JMenuItem DosyaItem;

    menubar () {
        Dosya = new JMenu("Dosya");


        DosyaItem = new JMenuItem("Dosya1");
        DosyaItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //desktop. here is the problem
            System.out.println();
            }
        });
        Dosya.add(DosyaItem);
        add(Dosya);


    }

}
```

Comment: The `desktop` variable is located inside an anonymous inner class, so it can only be referenced in that scope.  You need to put that variable in a publicly accessible scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass the JDesktopPane into the JMenuBar class:

```
        JDesktopPane desktop = new JDesktopPane();
        frame.add(desktop);

        menubar  mb = new menubar(desktop); // pass in the reference
```

then in your menubar class:

```
public class menubar extends JMenuBar {
    private JDesktopPane desktop;

    JMenu Dosya;
    JMenuItem DosyaItem;

    menubar (JDesktopPane desktop) {
        this.desktop = desktop;
        Dosya = new JMenu("Dosya");
```

This way menubar has a reference to the displayed JDesktopPane

---

Some side notes:

- You will want to learn and adhere to the Java naming conventions. Class names should all begin with an upper-case letter, and method and variable names with a lower-case letter. Follow this and others will be able to better follow your code.
- I'm not sure why your menubar class extends JMenuBar since it does not override any of the methods of this class.
- You've got too much code in the Runnable that is being started by the main method. You'll likely want to put much of that code in a class, and get it out of the static realm.

Comment: then should i change modifier to final ? [link](http://s27.postimg.org/ntxoxn3ar/aaa.png)

Comment: @user2778565: final is almost always a good modifier to use. If you need to use it in an anonymous inner way off of the constructor, then yes, it will need to be a final parameter.

Comment: Now my program runs. Thanks.
My menubar extends jmenubar because i want to simply my code. to shorten main method